# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/.... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, exist-db

**I am trying to retrieve an XML response using ajax calls to the eXist DB REST API(1).**

Google Chrome provides me the following console error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/movies?_query=%2Fmovies. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

While Firebug in Firefox provides the following console error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/movies?_query=%2Fmovies 200 OK X 35ms jquery.min.js(line 18)
```

Here is the ajax portion of the code:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/movies',
                    data: {
                        _query: _query_value,
                        _key: _key_value,
                        _indent: _indent_value,
                        _encoding: _encoding_value,
                        _howmany: _howmany_value,
                        _start: _start_value,
                        _wrap: _wrap_value,
                        _source: _source_value,
                        _cache: _cache_value
                    },
                    success: function(resp){
                        alert("Resp OK!");
                        console.log(resp);
                    },
                    error: function(hqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        var x=0;
                        alert("fail0 " + hqXHR + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

I have read some related issues on this same problem, but I have found no luck with any of the solution that I tried.

The index.html which contains the ajax code segment above is accessed from my local machine as follows:

```
file:///.../index.html
```

I have tried executing chrome as follows:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Also, I tried to deploy the file to an online host so that it is located at

```
http://www.<somedomain>.com/index.html
```

The closest solution that I had was to change the dataType of the from xml to jsonp. The reponse was received, but since it is expected to be xml, the error became related to parsing, I think, with the following statement returned by the Google Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

and Firebug console:

```
XML can't be the whole program
[Break On This Error]   
</exist:result>
movies...3302057 (line 528, col 15)
```

**Going back to my question, how can I properly retrieve the xml document via eXist DB? What am I doing wrong?**

Looking forward to your help. I'm quite new to web development and am running out of ideas.

Thanks in advance!

**Other notes:**

The jquery.min.js that I'm using is located at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

The URI `http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/movies?_query=%2Fmovies` works when directly keyed in to any browser.

**Reference:**

```
(1) - http://www.exist-db.org/exist/devguide_rest.xml;jsessionid=e7096vtg4l7gmocouhe6zhle
```

**Updates**
(1) It seems that I was able to get rid of the CORS problem by running eXist DB as a server as follows: bin/server.sh (in UNIX) or bin\server.bat (in Windows).

Now, I am running into another type of problem, though. I get the following error in the Google Chrome console using jquery.js:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/movies?_query=%2Fmovies  jquery.js:8240
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send jquery.js:8240
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7719
(anonymous function) index.html:43
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3332
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery.js:2941
```

and using jquery.min.js:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/movies?_query=%2Fmovies  jquery.min.js:18
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send jquery.min.js:18
f.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:18
(anonymous function) index.html:43
f.event.handle jquery.min.js:17
f.event.add.i.handle.k jquery.min.js:16
```

What does the error mean? Which part of my code am I doing wrongly?

(2) Update 1, apparently, is an unnecessary problem that I faced. The server mode wasn't working with my machine that's why the errors above showed up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a cross-domain request and is not permitted. Test from localhost instead of file://. Additionally, the remote server needs to return the proper [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers if it is intended to work cross-domain with any dataType other than JSONP. The JSONP datatype is not meant for returning XML.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to read about CORS. Then I tried to run eXist DB as a server instead of the usual startup and now I don't get the same origin error. It's probably returning the proper CORS headers with this setting. Now, I have another set of errors which looks foreign to me. It is in the updates section of the question. Do you know what is still wrong in my code?

Comment: The errors look foreign to me too. Are you sure you are looking at the right area in the console?

Comment: Yes, I was looking at the correct console, but there was something else that I did wrongly. I overlooked the fact that in server mode, eXist wasn't working at all for my machine. Therefore, my requests were being sent to a nonexistent service. I ended up with the original problem, but tried to run the file from the localhost as you advised and it worked. Thanks a lot!