# XMLHttpRequest cannot load the url Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

The **json response** is in

```
{"userName":"clevermeal835","userRole":"Participant"}
```

I am getting  alert message as success but while reading the response I am getting the error as

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load the url Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

If i run the code from command prompt by --disable-web-security I am getting response
                 The below is code.

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta charset="UTF-8">  
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  
                     <script>  
        $(document).ready(  
        function() {  
        $("#jsonpbtn2").click(function() {  
            var uid = "clevermeal835";  
            var pwd = "Welcome_1";  
            var userType = "participant";  
            var surl="http://localhost:8080/RESTlet_WS/MobiSignIn/{\"userName\":\""+uid+"\",\"password\":\""+pwd+"\",\"userType\":\""+userType+"\"}/";  
                $.ajax({  
                    type : 'GET',  
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    url : surl,  
                    dataType : 'json',  
                    headers : {Accept : "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"},  
                    crossDomain : true,  
                    success :SucceedFunc ,
                    error : function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("error"+' '+JSON.stringify(data) + ' ' + textStatus + '  ' + errorThrown);  
                    }
                    });  
                    function SucceedFunc(data) {
                        alert("success");
                        var userName = data.userName;
                        alert(userName);
                    }
                    });  
                });  
    </script>   
    </head>  
    <body>  
    <input id="jsonpbtn2" type="submit" value="button" />  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: Could you provide at least a sample of **how** you are making the request? Are you trying to call across domains?

Comment: just now I have placed code can you please verify it and help me

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you are treating this as a cross-domain request when you are making a call to **localhost**? What is your reasoning for doing that?

Comment: If I remove that crossDomain : true I am getting same error

Comment: what is the url of this page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling, the html page `ajaxCallPage.html` in the question above, like `file://.../ajaxCallPage.html` then you are doing it wrong.

Put the `ajaxCallPage.html` file in your web server and call it like this `http:/localhost:8080/.../ajaxCallPage.html`. Then this error would not come up.

If thats the case, this question is a possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/.... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822514/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-http-localhost8080-exist-rest-db-origin-null)

Comment: In place of localhost I am placing ipaddress.If I remove how can i get the response from webserver and I have tried it too

Comment: what is the url of the page you've pasted above in the question ?

Comment: I'm asking this to verify if this is truly a cross-domain XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/RESTlet_WS/MobiSignIn/{\"userName\":\""+uid+"\",\"password\":\""+pwd+"\",\"userType\":\""+userType+"\"}/ this is the url i am using and  uid = "clevermeal835" , pwd = "Welcome_1" ,userType = "participant";